Monolog in php is making m web server not working
Im making tests on a web server, showing a line if i go to a link within this server, it works fine but i wanted to implement monolog to check every time someone logs in and write it on a file.
The code below
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../utils/Requests.php';
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$logFilePath = __DIR__ . '/../../log/debug.log';
if (!file_exists($logFilePath)) {
    file_put_contents($logFilePath, '');
}

try {

    $logger = new Logger("daily");
    $stream_handler = new StreamHandler($logFilePath, Logger::DEBUG);
    $logger->pushHandler($stream_handler);
} catch (Exception $e) {

   echo "Error al inicializar el logger: " . $e->getMessage();
}


class HomeService extends Requests
{

    public function index()
    {
        global $logger;
        $logger->debug("HomeService index method called");

        $method = $this->getMethod();
        $result = [];

        if($method == 'GET') {
            http_response_code(200);
            $result = [
                "message" => "Hey There! ",
                "guide" => "https://github.com/EricNeves/myBooksAPI"
            ];
        } else {
            $logger->debug("HTTP method not allowed: " . $method);
            http_response_code(405);
            $result['error'] = "HTTP Method not allowed";
        }
        $logger->debug("Response: " . json_encode($result));
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
}
$homeService = new HomeService();
$homeService->index();

works if i execute it through the console and it saves the log on the file but if i try to go to the link to call this funciton, it gives an error 500 and doesnt show nothing unless i comment everything logger related inside the index function, it gives back this error
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-uncaught-exception' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function debug() on null in /var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/app/services/HomeService.php on line <i>33</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Error: Call to a member function debug() on null in /var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/app/services/HomeService.php on line <i>33</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0003</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>362224</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0005</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>364240</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Core->run(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../index.php<b>:</b>35</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0011</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>367000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>require_once( <font color='#00bb00'>'/var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/app/services/HomeService.php</font> )</td><td title='/var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/app/core/Core.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../Core.php<b>:</b>33</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>4</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0038</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>378264</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>HomeService->index(  )</td><td title='/var/www/html/prova_API/myBooksAPI-main/app/services/HomeService.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>.../HomeService.php<b>:</b>54</td></tr>
</table></font>

I tried giving all permissions to the file and directory but it doesnt work, i dont get why it works through console but not when i do it through the page

Try putting the logger initialization into the constructor of the class HomeService  and save the logger as a property of the class.

evidently $logger is null when the class is initialised, then. Are you sure there was no exception when intialising the logger? I notice that your code catches and shows an exception when the logger fails to initialise, but doesn't actually stop the script from continuing. Therefore, the system would continue to run and try to use a logger which doesn't exist. That sounds like the most likely explanation for the problem, but you haven't mentioned seeing the Error al inicializar el logger... message in your output.

But yeah Med is right, why are you using globals for accessing the logger instance, instead of dependency injection? That 1990s called and want their atrocious programming techniques back... :-)

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../utils/Requests.php';
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

class HomeService extends Requests
{
    private $logger;

    public function index()
    {
        $logFilePath = __DIR__ . '/../../log/debug.log';
        if (!file_exists($logFilePath)) {
            file_put_contents($logFilePath, '');
        }

        try {
            $this->logger = new Logger("daily");
            $stream_handler = new StreamHandler($logFilePath, Logger::DEBUG);
            $this->logger->pushHandler($stream_handler);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error al iniciar el logger: " . $e->getMessage();
            return;
        }

        $this->logger->debug("HomeService cridat");

        $method = $this->getMethod();
        $result = [];

        if($method == 'GET') {
            http_response_code(200);
            $result = [
                "message" => "Hey There! ",
                "guide" => "https://github.com/EricNeves/myBooksAPI"
            ];
        } else {
            $this->logger->debug("HTTP method not allowed: " . $method);
            http_response_code(405);
            $result['error'] = "HTTP Method not allowed";
        }
        $this->logger->debug("Response: " . json_encode($result));
        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    }
}

$homeService = new HomeService();
$homeService->index();
?>

Thanks to Med for the answer
